# Use Secure WebSocket in Local network

Tags: c#, android, kotlin, websocket

I want to build a remote app to control my PC from my Android. Currently I use a Fleck Websocket in my PC C# project and the default WebSocketClient with Kotlin on the Android and a "password" for authentication but since it's not wss this is a pretty unsecure solution.
I want to secure the connection using wss instead of ws, but I need a general idea on how to approach this. Can I generate a certificate on the PC and transfer it to the Android e.g. via QR-Code? Or should I build a AES layer using said passphrase?

Thanks in advance
Robin

Comment: You are combining both TLS and Authentication in your request.  TLS is used with HTTPS which uses a certificate to encrypt the entire message (headers and body).  Authentication is used after the connection completes to allow access to the server. WSS is windows authentication which is slowly being replace with OAUTH 2.0 since OAUTH can be used with Windows, Linux, and MAC.  When using HTTPS the OAUTH password is encrypted using TLS which makes it secure.

Comment: @jdweng Up until now I'm not using anything that encrypts the traffic as a whole, but I want to accomplish a tls-like security. Since I'm not sure how or whether this works with the websocket protocol I asked for a general idea on how to proceed.

Comment: The main different between webclient and websocket is the webclient closes the connection after each request/response which the websocket keeps the connection open.